Raid 5, single disk failure
A friend's Raid 5 array going down.
OS: Windows 10 on SSD, not on RAID
Raid controller: HighPoint RocketRAID 2720 controller
Raid 5 of 8x8TB drives
HighPoint controller is managed through their management tool called HighPoint Management server, the install on the PC was somehow corrupted, I reinstalled it, both the command line and browser end was usable again. The management server shows the raid is auto rebuilding, all 8 devices were marked healthy SMART,  devices 1/1, 1/2, 1/4 - 1/8 has no bad sector, while device 1/3 has a worrying bad sector count of 1,200.
During all this the array drive (F:) has been visible, as we opened it to browse some files the explorer window froze, management server window showed device 1/3 bad sector jumped to 1,600. Then some drive went offline again, Raid controller fired alarm again and BSOD.
I turned off PC and advised him not turning it on till we find some HDD raid expert tomorrow. What should we do next?
EDIT: I know I should replace the faulty drive with a fresh one, but I don't know which physical drive is device 3. We didn't build the array.

There should be a pre-boot environment to control and configure the RAID. This is usually where any such rebuilding activities should be done, so that you are not running the risk of attempting to read from the drives or otherwise access/use them during this process. When you say you have "1-drive abundance", so you mean you have "1 drive redundancy", perhaps? You probably already know this, but you should not have accessed that data while it was rebuilding, this is one of several reasons why rebuilding RAID is best done before booting any OS, if possible.

Also, I understand you're dealing multiple factors here, but you are also currently asking multiple questions. This site deals with single questions, so choose one of your questions, the one most critical and important to you, and edit your question to remove the other questions and focus on just that one.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.


If you get the data back, RAID strategy - 8 1TB drives suggests using RAID 6 for that many drives, especially considering the size of the drives. 2) It might be quicker to buy all new drives and restore from the backup.


You didn't mention a new HDD, so have you read the instructions on how to replace the faulty drive?
